# Auto play (Responsive voice text to speech) not working in WKWebview

Tags: ios

I am trying to load a webpage into WKWebView which contains Responsive JS text to speech. Web page auto plays the text to speech when it finishes loading.

But inside the app the text to speech auto play not working when the page is loaded. It only works if I fire a javascript method through button click inside the app.

Is it possible to auto play when load the page? If is it possible how can I get it done.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
config.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = NO;

wkWebview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) configuration:config];
wkWebview.navigationDelegate = self;
[self.view insertSubview:wkWebview atIndex:0];

NSURL *url;
url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.content objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"URL"]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[wkWebview loadRequest:request];


button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Here is button action

```
- (IBAction)aMethod:(id)sender
{
     [wkWebview evaluateJavaScript:@"document.getElementsByName('Play')[0].click()" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable sds, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for using ResponsiveVoice!

Apple prevents you from taking actions in javascript without the user initiating them. For example you cannot play audio, redirect the page, or, in this case, play TTS.

In Safari (probably will be the same in WebView) this only needs to be done once. So the first click from the user would remove this limitation. You can, for example, place a "Start" button and use it to play a blank text (" "). That will allow you to launch TTS from code next time.

ResponsiveVoice does that for you, you only need to attach this function to the click event of any object:

```
object.addEventListener("click", responsiveVoice.clickEvent);
```

Then you will be able to call speak() as usual.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Juan. The problem is I am trying to load TTS to web view when user hits play button.